# Auth fail while importing source dependencies from private git repository with gradle

Tags: git, gradle, ssh, android-gradle-plugin, jscharts

I'm using Android studio and I would like to convert part of my kotlin/java project to a library. I'll be using Gradle to fetch sources as described [here](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies). Except I'll be using a private git repository with ssh access.

I created new ssh key pairs without passphrase and tested them, evething works fine when used directly.

I use this in my `settings.gradle`:

```
sourceControl {
gitRepository('ssh://git@example-vcs/username/my-private-lib.git') {
        producesModule('com.example:my-private-lib')
    }
}
```

Build fails because of a `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail`. And it says `Could not locate branch 'release'` although it actually exists.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':distTar'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not locate branch 'release' for Git repository at ssh://git@example-vcs/username/my-private-lib.git.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':distTar'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfo.getDependencies(LocalTaskInfo.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfo.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskInfo.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:168)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:126)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$CalculateTaskGraph.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.constructTaskGraph(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:190)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:145)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$5.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:533)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:524)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:509)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1514)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:211)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:64)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not locate branch 'release' for Git repository at ssh://git@example-vcs/username/my-private-lib.git.
    at org.gradle.vcs.internal.services.DefaultVersionControlRepositoryFactory$LockingVersionControlRepository.getBranch(DefaultVersionControlRepositoryFactory.java:117)
    at org.gradle.vcs.internal.resolver.DefaultVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver.selectVersionFromRepository(DefaultVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver.java:76)
    at org.gradle.vcs.internal.resolver.DefaultVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver.selectVersion(DefaultVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver.java:52)
    at org.gradle.vcs.internal.resolver.OncePerBuildInvocationVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver$1.create(OncePerBuildInvocationVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver.java:52)
    at org.gradle.vcs.internal.resolver.OncePerBuildInvocationVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver$1.create(OncePerBuildInvocationVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.vcs.internal.resolver.OncePerBuildInvocationVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver.selectVersion(OncePerBuildInvocationVcsVersionWorkingDirResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.vcs.internal.resolver.VcsDependencyResolver.resolve(VcsDependencyResolver.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$DependencyToComponentIdResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.SelectorState.resolve(SelectorState.java:170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.selectors.SelectorStateResolver.resolveSelectors(SelectorStateResolver.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.selectors.SelectorStateResolver.selectBest(SelectorStateResolver.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.performSelection(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.performSelectionSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:155)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:167)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:73)
    ... 106 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not run ls-remote for ssh://git@example-vcs/username/my-private-lib.git
    at org.gradle.vcs.git.internal.GitVersionControlSystem.wrapGitCommandException(GitVersionControlSystem.java:185)
    at org.gradle.vcs.git.internal.GitVersionControlSystem.getRemoteRefs(GitVersionControlSystem.java:107)
    at org.gradle.vcs.git.internal.GitVersionControlSystem.getBranch(GitVersionControlSystem.java:91)
    at org.gradle.vcs.internal.services.DefaultVersionControlRepositoryFactory$LockingVersionControlRepository.getBranch(DefaultVersionControlRepositoryFactory.java:115)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@example-vcs/username/my-private-lib.git: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
    at org.gradle.vcs.git.internal.GitVersionControlSystem.getRemoteRefs(GitVersionControlSystem.java:103)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@example-vcs/username/my-private-lib.git: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:198)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:117)
    ... 134 more
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with the same problem and just want to add my investigation's results.
`Auth fail` means that JGit **couldn't find and/or load ssh key**.
The easiest way to find it out is to add a `config` file to your `~/.ssh/` directory with content like this:

```
# Private GitLab server
Host <YOUR GIT HOST>
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<YOUR_SSH_KEY>
```

It can help in case you have a valid RSA key and just with a different name (not `id_rsa`).
In my case I've got another exception:

```
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@e4487af
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:664)
```

And this one means that your ssh key is not RSA type.
The problem is - Gradle uses JGit with jsch ssh implementation, but not with Apache MINA. 
And jsch support only **RSA and DSA** key types.

***Recent versions of OpenSSH (7.8 and newer) generate keys in new OpenSSH format by default (ed25519 or some another, but not RSA).***
So, the easy way to fix the problem is just to generate correct RSA key using the command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

This should work fine even without the unnecessary `config` file.
But, of course, it's kind of crutch, and I'm still trying to find some way to configure Gradle or better to say configure JGit through Gradle to use Apache MINA sshd implementation, with support new ssh key types.

Comment: I want to precise if you want everythin work you need to get a ssh_key without passphrase.

Comment: [It has been reported to JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1850814/?srch=ssh+key#msg_1850814) and running `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -E sha256 -m PEM` will not work either.

Comment: This does not work anymore, because GitHub is blocking any RSA keys and [JGit is still using the same JSch version that is end-of-life](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1110330&goto=1850825&#msg_1850825).

Comment: It's been addressed in gradle already: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8245

Answer (score 1):

We experienced this issue earlier today, and got away with somewhat of a hacky fix. If you're building from command line, you can try setting the `GIT_SSH` environment variable as below:

```
export GIT_SSH=ssh
```

If that doesn't work you can also try:

```
export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
```

I'm not entirely sure why this works, it's likely a nuance with JGit.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can't try it right now as I'm stuck with a new error: " Git repository at ssh://git@---- did not contain a project publishing the specified dependency".

Comment: I guess this means that the repo is now accessible through ssh, but I don't know why it now works. I also don't understand this new error.

Comment: Are you using GitLab by any chance?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I there something specific to gitlab ?